# Would it sound strange to use the adverb "dreadfully" in (North)American English?

Tags: transatlantic-differences

I was reading about "grading" and "non-grading" adverbs, came across with the adverb ***dreadfully***. Surprisingly, I found that there are two sources mentioning the adverb as **chiefly British** [[1]](https://www.google.com/#q=dreadfully+definition), [[2]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dreadfully). However, there are other sources that do not mention similar thing. That motivated me to ask about this adverb.

Comment: It's not in the vocabulary of most speakers of American English as a synonym for "very".   An American can do dreadfully on an exam. But he does not get dreadfully sleepy.

Comment: The same could go for 'terribly'. This is also mainly British and Commonwealth usage but an American using it need not have to feel he is saying something stilted.

Comment: @tom: My impression is that *terribly* is quite common in American English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second source, the *Oxford dictionary (online)* says 'chiefly British'. That is its UK version. Its [US version](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/dreadfully) does not say 'Chiefly British'. Which version are you goin to believe? By the way, I don't see what your first reference is pointing to, so that it says the word is 'chiefly British'.

*Dreadfully* can mean *terribly*, as in *I'm terribly/dreadfully tired.*. It is also synonymous with *awfully* and *horribly*. None of these words would seem overly strange to speakers of American English.

The ***American*** Heritage Dictionary lists [one definition](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dreadfully) of *dreadfully* as

> Extremely; very: *was dreadfully ill; a dreadfully boring book; dreadfully exciting.*

So, no.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I was confused. I learned something new which is checking American version rather British version. So far, I did not care about that.